# how to get notify when someone change db manually through sqldependency?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, sqldependency

I want to make a method which call automatically when someone make changes in db in sqlsever.
or where I have to call this? now it's in the childHub Hub class.
here are my functions but not working.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want to use Signalr to update a page with changes, is that correct? I suggest you first look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio and update your answer with what you tried.

For example, where do you call your `SQLDependencyMessage()`?

Comment: I have post my answer, hope it can help you, it also [has video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SJrag0UiTY). Pls refer the sample code. If it useful to you, could accept my answer, tks.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't get more info from your code.  When the data in the database is modified, you can get a message notification.

And Rule's comment is also useful, if you want get notification in time, you should use SignalR.

I found a good github repo for you, when the data was modified, it will send message to Dashboard.

[SignalR with SqlTableDependency in Asp.Net Core](https://github.com/Skynet-Demos/SignalR-SqlTableDependency)